# R: Opening file in UTF-8

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use another R file from my shiny program.

```
source(page1_ui, encoding = "UTF-8", local = TRUE)
```

And page contains some non-latin text. That's the message which I am getting:

```
page1_ui.R:7:34: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
```

I'm already in doubt, I've tried to convert this file to window's specific encoding windows1251 but it still doesn't help.

Is there any way to make R work with unicode pages?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251
```

Comment: [This may help](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/818)

Comment: I'm invoking Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','Russian'), but it doesn't help

Comment: Just because it's non-latin doesn't mean it's necessarily UTF-8. You need to know the encoding of the file because there is no 100% safe way to guess. How exactly did you try to convert the encoding of the file? What if you leave the `encoding=` parameter off?

Comment: I know that file is in UTF8, it's sure. I've tried to remove encoding, it compiles, runs, but then on shiny page I have damaged text. like this: РљР»Р°СЃСЃ

Comment: so far what i have found -eval(parse(page1_ui.R, encoding = "UTF-8")), this at least works.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a long-standing but in `source`. There is a report at https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17332 and a discussion at https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-August/074832.html

Comment: @Ista thanks for posting this link, very helpful